# Cannot use chrome.management API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Now I want to start a chrome app from a chrome extension(in fact, I want to start chrome app through a url, which I have no idea to do). 
Here comes the question. I added

```
  "permissions": [
    "management"
  ],
```

in the manifest of extension. However, when I want to start app by using

```
chrome.management.launchApp("XXXX", function() {});
```

, the console says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'launchApp' of undefined

So I wonder why I cannot use chrome management API. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I try using chrome.management in both background scripts and content scripts, finally found it is only valid in background scripts, so @janindu is providing an answer which is on the right way.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is available at the SO question [Run chrome application from a web site button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31800690/run-chrome-application-from-a-web-site-button/34940239#34940239)

Copying [Hasitha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629993/hasitha)'s answer here for direct reference.

- Add the following piece of code where you want to invoke the chrome app

  ```
                                                   //data passed from web to chrome app
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('your_chrome_app_id', { message: "version" },
      function (reply) {
          if (reply) {
              if (reply.version) {
                  //log the response received from the chrome application
                  console.log(reply.version);
              }
          }
      }
   );
  ```
- in your chrome application **manifest.json** define the `externally_connectable` url/ urls as follows,

  {
            "name": "App name",
            "description": "App Desc",
            "version": "1",

  ```
        ...

        "externally_connectable": {
          "matches": ["*://localhost:*/"]
        }
      }
  ```
- In your application **background.js** setup a listener to be invoked when a message is sent from the web page as follows,

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request) {
        if (request.message) {
          if (request.message == "version") {

            //my chrome application initial load screen is login.html
            window.open('login.html');

            //if required can send a response back to the web site aswell. I have logged the reply on the web site
            sendResponse({version: '1.1.1'});
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
  ```