# How to access Chrome extensions Details from webpage?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to know if its possible to access any chrome extension details from a webpage

Comment: plugin !== extension

Comment: Sorry Wrong Fiddle

Comment: Which details? Anyway, web pages don't have access to chrome.management API.

Comment: But this seems to be Possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382305/cannot-use-chrome-management-api

Comment: Are you wanting the information from an extension that is cooperating with your website (e.g. you also wrote the extension), or just any random extension?